# How to use environment variables at build time in a VueJS project

Tags: javascript, vue.js, npm, gitlab-ci

I'm trying to use an environment variable during the `build` stage of a CI job for a VueJS app. I'm using GitLab CI, and one of the environment variables that is made available is `CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA`,

```
build:
  image: node:latest
  stage: build
  variables:
    CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA: "$CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA"
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - dist/
  script:
    - npm install --progress=false
    - npm run build
    - echo "Build Complete"
```

Here's how I'm trying to use this variable in Vue:

```
<template>
  <div class="hello">
    <h1>{{ msg }}</h1>
    <p>This is a static site that is served with a CloudFront distribution in front of an S3 bucket.</p>
    <p>The site is updated through a GitLab CI/CD pipeline.</p>
    <p>Commit ref: {{ commit }}</p>
    <p>Using cache invalidation</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'HelloWorld',
  props: {
    msg: String
  },
  data(){
    return {
      commit: process.env.CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

I'm not seeing this variable come through. Is there something else I need to do in order to access the environment variable and display it in my component?

Comment: Are you using webpack to compile your SFC?

Comment: @CodyG. I should add that this is a Vue CLI 3 generated project. So yes it is using webpack under the hood

Comment: Well, `process.env.CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA` is probably in your exported code, which when run in the browser obviously it doesn't have that ... I'm not sure how to include it off the top of my head but I'm looking into it

Comment: right, so I'm trying to figure out how to use this kind of environment variable during build time

Comment: What I would do... personally... is have your build process spit out a server_props.js file that you just import into your vue template... so server_props.js : `module.exports = { vue_server_props: { commit: blahblah } }` and then in your vue template `import {vue_server_props} from './config.js;` and then put that into your data()

Comment: You can also get fancy and have webpack replace the string "process.env.CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA" in your code, but I really don't like those.

Comment: @CodyG. Ok thanks for the suggestions, I'm also going to try prefixing `VUE_APP` to the variable name, someone in VueLand said that this is the way to do it

Comment: Indeed it is https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html#using-env-variables-in-client-side-code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html#using-env-variables-in-client-side-code

> Only variables that start with `VUE_APP_` will be statically embedded into the client bundle with `webpack.DefinePlugin`. You can access them in your application code:
>
> `console.log(process.env.VUE_APP_SECRET)`

Answer (score 4):

If you're using `webpack.config`, you can set up `DefinePlugin` in a similar way.

In your `webpack.config.js` you would use a new plugin,

```
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
  /* 
    JSON.stringify(yourconfig) is highly recommened 
    to avoid overwriting existing keysother process.env
  */
  'process.env': JSON.stringify(config.prod), // or config.dev
}),
```

Where `config.prod` / `config.dev` is something like

```
let config = {};
config.prod = require('./config/prod.env'); // imports ./config/prod.env.js
config.dev = require('./config/dev.env');
```

at the top of the file,

and the `prod.env.js` and `dev.env.js` files look something like

```
'use strict';
module.exports = {
  VUE_APP_MODE: 'MYMODE'
};
```

If you wanted to match the vue process more closely,you could filter out the object keys using RegExp `/^VUE_APP_.*/`.

Then in the data section of your .vue file you can include these by using:

```
data: {
  VUE_APP_MODE: process.env.VUE_APP_MODE
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After some research it seemed that the `vue-cli-service build` command only looks into the dot-files in the root of your project, and only processes these variables starting with `VUE_APP_` (in various .env files)

You could set all the variables in the Gitlab CI options and then copy those variables to the .env file. Now, when vue-cli builds the project, it injects these values in the transpiled scripts.

You could issue a command like this before you build the project:

```sh
env | grep 'VUE_APP_' > .env
```

I also use a staging environment that is built when pushing into the staging branch. Therefore I have these variables set into Gitlab:

- VUE_APP_VAR1=foo
- VUE_APP_VAR2=bar
- VUE_ACCEPT_VAR1=foo
- VUE_ACCEPT_VAR2=bar

Since vue-cli wants the variables to start with `VUE_APP_` I do a replace with sed:

```sh
env | grep 'VUE_ACCEPT_' | sed 's/VUE_ACCEPT_/VUE_APP_/' > .env
```