# How to fix vuejs env variables not beeing used

Tags: vue.js, environment-variables

The problem is that I am not able to use env variables, associated with Vue (Using Typescript, if that makes any difference). When declaring an URL for an endpoint and trying to serve, it just uses localhost, which leads me to believe that something in my setup is not done properly.

I've tried setting it up following Vue's own documentation:
https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html#modes

Furthermore I've tryed following this guy, which is excatly what I need:
https://code-maze.com/vuejs-axios-http-environment-files/

I've tried a few more different approaches, all with the same result, but theese two are the most topical ones.

Maybe it has something with my setup in my tsconfig.json to do, but to be honest, I'm not sure where the fault could be.

```
//tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./built/",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "module": "es2015",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "es2016",
      "dom"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "./src/"
  ]
}
```

I've read some solutions where webpack plays in, but as far as I know this should not be needed, since Vue uses its own web bundling.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54792619/how-to-use-environment-variables-at-build-time-in-a-vuejs-project/54793307#54793307

Comment: Most importantly, "Only variables that start with VUE_APP_ will be statically embedded into the client bundle with webpack.DefinePlugin." note that you don't have to use webpack, but vue is doing this under the hood.

Comment: Thank you! Dont know how I missed that part..

Comment: Because it's one sentence in a sea of documentation! haha Also, welcome to S.O.!

Comment: I also installed my vue project with PWA enabled, I wasnt planning on using it, but didn't think it would do any harm. It seams though, that since it doesn't create an index.html, it is not possible to use env variables, since they are bundled into the index.html. I don't know if this is working as designed, but I had to create a new project, without PWA, to get env variables working.

Comment: That's an interesting note! I don't necessarily know enough about PWA to understand why or why not that is the case. FYI feel free to post an answer to your own question.