# How to inject Git commit hash using Gitlab to Vue app?

Tags: vue.js, gitlab

I would like to print Git hash into footer of my Vue.js app. I have followed instructions in this question:

[How to use environment variables at build time in a VueJS project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54792619/how-to-use-environment-variables-at-build-time-in-a-vuejs-project)

But just can't get it to work. process.env.VUE_APP_GIT_COMMIT variable is not set for the app. Variables set in .env files work just fine.

.gitlab.ci.yml:

```
build-frontend:    
   image: node:10.16.3-stretch  
   stage: build
   before_script:
      - cd frontend
   variables:
      VUE_APP_GIT_COMMIT: "$CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA"      
   script:
      - npm install -g @vue/cli@3.11.0   
      - npm install    
      - npm run staging
   artifacts:    
      paths:
         - frontend/dist/ 
      expire_in: 1 hour

deploy-staging-frontend:  
   image: python:3.7.4
   stage: deploy  
   script:    
      - pip install awscli   
      - aws s3 sync --delete frontend/dist s3://bucket
```

Comment: Try to write:  

`before_script:
    - echo "VUE_APP_GIT_COMMIT=$CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA" >> .env`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after some research it seemed that the `vue-cli-service build` command only looks into the dot-files in the root of your project. (various .env files)

You could set all the variables in the Gitlab CI options and then, as Sergey stated in the comments, copy those variables to the .env file. Now, when vue-cli builds the project, it injects these values in the transpiled scripts.

You could issue a command like this before you build the project:

```sh
env | grep 'VUE_APP_' > .env
```

I also use a staging environment that is built when pushing into the staging branch. Therefore I have these variables set into Gitlab:

- VUE_APP_VAR1=foo
- VUE_APP_VAR2=bar
- VUE_ACCEPT_VAR1=foo
- VUE_ACCEPT_VAR2=bar

Since vue-cli wants the variables to start with `VUE_APP_` I do a replace with sed:

```sh
env | grep 'VUE_ACCEPT_' | sed 's/VUE_ACCEPT_/VUE_APP_/' > .env
```